# HTML5 Audio is not working with setTimeout method

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am fairly new to JavaScript and jQuery, what I'm doing is actually calling a function with an array of some colors, initially it is `['blue', 'green']`
And I runs a for-loop on this array to play sound specific to each number.

But the problem is, it just plays sound with the last parameter. Why so?
I want to play both, (or how many I adjust) sounds to be played after a fixed interval (like here I've 1000ms). Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
function singPattern(compPattern) {
    var audio;
    for(let i=0; i<compPattern.length; i++) {

        audio = new Audio("../../music-files/" + compPattern[i] + ".mp3");
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            audio.play();
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: `audio` get overridden every iteration of the loop. Make an array or dictionary to hold them.

Comment: But every time I've new audio file already stored in compPattern[i]. Then what's the point of making array of audio? Please show a modified code example if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
function singPattern(compPattern) {
    var audio; // There is only one audio
    for(let i=0; i<compPattern.length; i++) {

        //everytime in this loop audio is assigned to the "Audio" 
        //  the old one is off to the pasture. (dead)(GC) 
        audio = new Audio("../../music-files/" + compPattern[i] + ".mp3");
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            audio.play();
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Like in all things javascript, There are several ways to handle this.

you could pass the object into the timeout like this. and the time out will have a closure of the object.

```
function singPattern(compPattern) {
    for(let i=0; i<compPattern.length; i++) {
        // I will just print the word but you can pass the object in. 
        var audio = compPattern[i] + ".mp3";
        window.setTimeout(function (_audio) {
            console.log(_audio)
        }, 2000, audio);
    }
}
```

If you need access to the `Audio` object outside of the setTimeout to cancel/replay it you could set up a dictionary like this :

```
function singPattern(compPattern) {
    var audio ={};
    for(let i=0; i<compPattern.length; i++) {       
        audio[compPattern[i]] = compPattern[i] + ".mp3";        
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
       for( var a in audio ){ console.log( "play ", a , audio[a] ); } 
    },2000);
    // audio['green'].pause() ?     
}
```

**Edit**

Heres a working sample with external mp3s

```js
function singPattern(compPattern) { 
  for (let i = 0; i < compPattern.length; i++) {  
    var audio = compPattern[i];         
    setTimeout(function (_audio) { 
      var sound = new Audio(_audio); 
      console.log("Playing " + _audio);
      sound.play(); 
    }, 2000, audio); 
  } 
}

var soundUrls = ["http://soundbible.com/mp3/Stream Noise-SoundBible.com-866411702.mp3", "http://soundbible.com/mp3/Strange_Days-Mike_Koenig-176042049.mp3"];

singPattern(soundUrls);
```

Comment: I tried your second code snippet, but it's still not working :(

`function singPattern(compPattern) {
        for (let i = 0; i < compPattern.length; i++) {
            // I will just print the word but you can pass the object in. 
            var audio = "../../music-files/" + compPattern[i] + ".mp3";
            window.setTimeout(function (_audio) {
                var sound = new Audio(_audio);
                sound.play();
            }, 2000, audio);
        }
    }`